# How to use Java to run an application in a web page coded with C++ and Direct9?

Tags: java, c++, web, directx

How can I use `Java` to insert an application coded with `C++` and Direct9 into a web page?

It is a simple program, only using 2D graphics, sound and input.

What do I have to use, a wrapper, applet?

Comment: Do you want to embed an applet in your website, or is the application not written as an applet?

Comment: @bennofs The application is written purely in Direct9 and C++ using Visual C++ Express IDE, it has nothing java related.

Comment: I don't think it is realistically possible to wrap an applet around a Windows-binary program. You'd have to run the program, and then somehow intercept the graphics, sound and Windows-UI commands output by the program, as well as feed it the correct user input (mouse position would be hard). I don't think it'd be realistic to implement.

Comment: @Ghostkeeper Can Java run DirectX code? I could change C++ to Java and recompile it, as the application is small.

Comment: No, Java doesn't run DirectX. But it can run native applications. But is not sure that will cover all your requirements. See this example: http://www.linglom.com/programming/java/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build JNI library in C++ and call it inside Java Apple. Inside that library you can do whatever your want, including using DirectX. See article on how you use native code inside applet: http://www.raditha.com/java/jni/

Comment: I didn't have much time lately, but I managed to run C++ code in the Java applet on my browser using JNI. However, how can I now do anything with Direct9? Direct9 creates a window and renders everything on it, whereas Java has its own window. Is there a way I can pass the render from Directx to Java, or differently achieve the same result?